# I have a problem with the function I have written which returns `None` as the result

Tags: python-3.x, list, function

```
def double_index(my_list, index):
  if index >= len(my_list):
    return my_list
  else:
    my_new_list = my_list.insert(index, my_list[index] ** 2)
    return my_new_list

print(double_index([3, 8, -10, 12], 2))
```

I was expecting to get `[3, 8, -20, -10, 12]`, however, I got `None`.
What mistake do you think I'm making here?

Comment: `insert` always returns `None`. See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html): *"You might have noticed that methods like `insert`, `remove` or `sort` that only modify the list have no return value printed – they return the default `None`. This is a design principle for all mutable data structures in Python."*.